# Settings background for EDITTEXT cutting words in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having a strange issue, the words are cutting inside EDITTEXT i have set an image as background. Plz help me... for example here ffsds, is being cut, I want it to shift to bit right so that it doesnt get cut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase `paddingLeft` value of edit text.

```
...
android:paddingLeft="100dp"
...
```

in xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the left padding is the easy solution. But if this smiley image is always on the left of the edittext, you can set the image by using the attribute android:drawableLeft on the edittext.